# É correto substituir o estive por tive, na forma falada, para indicar que esteve num sitio?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tempo-verbal

É correto substituir o estive por tive, na forma falada, para indicar que esteve num sitio?

São dois verbos diferentes , estar e ter.

É muito usual ouvir o tive . Exemplo: "Hoje de manhã, tive na cidade."

Comment: Na minha experiência, não é substituição de «estar» por «ter», mas sim uma forma suprimida de «estive», ou seja, «hoje de manhã, 'tive na cidade». Esse «'» indica supressão. Outro exemplo é «'to' na praia» em vez de «estou na praia».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto é "estive" o "tive" é um erro gramatical que é recorrente na linguagem falada, no cotidiano, ou seja é informal e por isso não deve ser utilizada em situações que requeira o português correto.

Comment: É possível encontrar uma demostração para a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo falou, é apenas uma redução que ocorre na informalidade (apesar de "tava em um (num) sítio" ser mais comum do que tive...)

Answer (score 0):

É gramaticalmente errado. Geralmente as pessoas usam em conversas informais apenas para diminuir a palavra.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site! No Portuguese StackExchange, tenta-se usar referências nos argumentos, respostas. Pelo teu perfil, és estudante de matemática, então acho que sabes como provar coisas. Para provar na matemática, usam-se premissas, como definições ou axiomas. Como sabe que [(a/b)^2=(a^2)/(b^2)] é verdade ou não? Provando. Algo parecido ocorre cá com as repostas. Uma resposta, como a tua, sem premissas tem o mesmo valor desta “está certo porque Santa Maria me disse”, mesmo que a tua resposta esteja ou não certa. Não sou matemático, então, posso ter falado alguma bobagem. Obg de qualquer modo.